# Unable to hide a field on an SSRS report

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I've written a report on SSRS which has an initial parameter that you select from. That then shows a specific set of records from a SQL database. However, dependent on that selection I want some of the fields to show or not show in the report.

The fields are listed as `Row Groups` [image: Report layout]

and I've gone into the `Group Properties`/`Visibility` and written the following under "show or hide based on an expression":

```
=IIf(Parameters!StoreType.Value = "xxxxx",true,false)
```

My impression was that would hide the column if what I specified was true and display it if it was false, however it's not working, it still shows that column associated with that "Group". I tried altering to "Fields" rather than "Parameters", but that has no effect either.

There are quite a few fields I would like to apply this to, but obviously I need to get one working before I roll it out to all the rest. If anyone can shed light on what I've done incorrectly/need to do differently that would be much appreciated.

Cheers,

Chris

Answer (score 0):

Put your expression on column visibility instead.

Right click the cell on top of column **Store Group** then select Column visibility.

Comment: Whilst I can right-click on the "Column" and bring up a menu with "Column Visibility" on, it's greyed out. I can access "Tablix Properties" on that same menu, but that affects the whole report, i.e. when I select the option I've specified as "true" nothing appears at all on the report, whereas the other options do show the data.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `Column Visibility` instead of Row.

[image]

Comment: As mentioned above, that option is greyed out.